# Is there a way to make a Input.GetButtonDown for all buttons but one in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

In a game im making I want to make a quick time event, which can be failed should the wrong button be pressed. But I dont know how I can make it so every button triggers it. Surely there must be an alternative to making Keycode for every button in void Update, right?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand it correctly, you want every button to act in some way except one. Let's call this the "wrong button". You can then distinguish this button by it's name or it's tag.

If the wrong button's tag is different you can compare the tag in Update() like this:

```
private string WrongButtonTag = "wrongButton";
void Update()
{
   if(Input.GetButtonDown("yourKey") && !this.CompareTag(WrongButtonTag))
   {
      //add your code logic for correct buttons here
   }

}
```

You might need to assign the tag beforehand though, for example by calling this function:

```
private void AssignWrongButtonTag()
{
    this.tag = WrongButtonTag;
}
```

Edit:

After the comment, I think this is the way to go: You have to put all your buttons into a list, and then use this code in the Update function:

```
public List<GameObject> buttonList = new List<GameObject>();
void Update()
    {
       if(Input.GetButtonDown(<your input key here>)
       {
          foreach(GameObject button in buttonList)
          { 
              if(!this.CompareTag(WrongButtonTag))
              {
                  continue;
              }
              //add your code logic for correct buttons here
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: I might have made a mistake while writing the question. I need all buttons but one to be considered wrong, sorry for it. Is there a command with which I can trigger an "Input.GetButtonDown(Keycode.)" for every single button but not the correct one?

Comment: How is that button different from others?

Comment: It shows an image which shows that player passed the Quick TIme Event

Comment: Thanks for the help, but how exactly can I add buttons to the list?

Comment: When you open Unity Editor, find the object that you attached this script into. Under that script, you will see a new field called "buttonList" (if you copied my code from above). You can then set the size (length) of the list, which will create slots for the buttons just below that. Then, you can drag and drop each button you want to use under this list object.

Comment: Excuse me, are we talking about UI buttons or Keyboard buttons? Because I need a keyboard buttons and there might have been a misunderstanding there

Comment: I was talking about UI buttons the whole time. Please clarify your questions before asking next time.

Comment: So tell me if this example is correct for you: You can press some keys in the scene, lets say these are Q,W,E and R. And R would be the wrong button in this case. You want to trigger the event for each button at the same time but not R. Is this correct?

Comment: Everything is right, but there are only one key that is NOT wrong.

Comment: Then you have to check for every button in Update, there is no alternative as far as I know that is simpler than this method.

Comment: I see, thank you and sorry for all the inconvenience.

Comment: No problem at all, happy to help :)